# ¿Cómo tomo los valores de muchas relaciones en Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Nose que relación debo utilizar en este caso, el `belongsTo` y `hasMany` no me han funcionado

Debo obtener el nombre de los lugares que se ven en estas tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*de la tabla paises el campo pais, de la tabla provincias el campo provincia, de la tabla partidos el campo partido, etc..*

**mi solución fue esta:**

```
    $companys = Empresas::all();
    foreach ($companys as $row) {
        $companys_load['nombre'] = $row->nombre;
        $companys_load['cuit'] = $row->cuit;
        $companys_load['direccion'] = $row->direccion;
        $companys_load['observaciones'] = $row->observaciones;
        $companys_load['telefono'] = $row->telefono;
        $companys_load['email'] = $row->email;
        $companys_load['activo'] = $row->activo;

        $localidad_bd = Localidades::select('id', 'partido_id', 'localidad')->where('id', $row->localidad_id)->first();
        $companys_load['id_localidad'] = $localidad_bd->id;
        $companys_load['localidad'] = $localidad_bd->localidad;

        $partido_bd = Partidos::select('id', 'provincia_id', 'partido')->where('id', $localidad_bd->partido_id)->first();
        $companys_load['id_partido'] = $partido_bd->id;
        $companys_load['partido'] = $partido_bd->partido;
        

        $provincia_bd = Provincias::select('id', 'pais_id', 'provincia')->where('id', $partido_bd->provincia_id)->first();
        $companys_load['id_provincia'] = $provincia_bd->id;
        $companys_load['provincia'] = $provincia_bd->provincia;
        

        $pais_bd = Paises::select('id', 'pais')->where('id', $provincia_bd->pais_id)->first();
        $companys_load['id_pais'] = $pais_bd->id;
        $companys_load['pais'] = $pais_bd->pais;

        $companys_return[] = $companys_load; 
    }
    return $companys_return;
```

acá se pueden ver los modelos relacionados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿hay alguna herramienta que me ofrezca `eloquent` para corregir esta mala practica? me puse a buscar en internet y no encontre nada respecto a mi duda.. desde ya gracias

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el criterio para obtener esos valores que quieres?

Comment: @betaM es una petición ajax, estos valores cargan una tabla en el frontend, con los valores: 
Nombre | Cuit | Dirección | Observaciones | Teléfono | Email | >Localidad< |

Y cuando haces click en >localidad< que te muestre el partido, provincia y país que está relacionada dicha información.. (las ID me sirven para modificar dichos valores, este método solo los imprime)

se que mi solución es pésima, y quisiera saber si Eloquent tiene una mejor solución ante la atrocidad que hice

Comment: A lo que voy es: ¿de las columnas mencionadas quieres obtener todos los registros?

Comment: @BetaM Así es, tal cual

Comment: Entonces considera editar y: explicar que relaciones existen entre los modelos y si tienes definidas las relaciones en tus modelos

Comment: Com dijo @BetaM explica cuales relaciones existen en tus modelos y pon las que ya definistes

Comment: Ah perdón, entendí mal, ahi mismo subo con imágen

Comment: usa hasMany, por lo que veo en tus tablas un pais tiene muchas provincias, una provincia tiene muchos partidos y muchos partidos tiene muchas localidades, con hasMany es el indicado para tu consulta.

Comment: @tecnobyte eso he hecho, pero igual hago varias consultas, quisiera saber si Eloquent ofrece una herramienta para evitar esto y hacerlo todo con un único código, o con buenas practicas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquen te ofrece la posibilidad de englobar una consulta con relaciones a una tabla, esto por medio de sus relaciones, para poder realizarlo tienes que especificar en el modelo cual es la relacion que tiene con la tabla, en este caso una localidad esta registrado a un partido, el ejemplo quedaría algo asi,

```
//Modelo de localidades
public funcion partido(){
   $this->belongsTo(Partidos::class, 'id_partido')
}
```

en tu consulta usarías with para unir todas las relaciones que tendría tu consulta:

```
Localidades::with([
   'Partidos'
])->select('id', 'partido_id', 'localidad')
->where('id', $row->localidad_id)
->first();
```

Al final te quedaría algo así:

```
Localidades::with([
   'partido:id,id_provincia,partido',
   'partido.provincia:id,id_pais,provincia',
   'partido.provincia.pais:id,id_pais,provincia'
])->select('id', 'id_partido', 'localidad')
->where('id', $row->localidad_id)
->first();
```

**Nota**: *puedes usar el comando tinker de laravel, eso te permitirá verificar si las consultas que estas realizando son correctas.*

El resultado serial una toda la información escalonada:

```
{
   id:1,
   id_partido:1,
   localidad:'X',
   partido: {
      id:1,
      id_provincia:1,
      partido:'X',
      provincia: {
         id:1,
         id_pais:1,
         provincia:'x',
         pais:{
            id:1,
            pais:'x'
         }
      }
   }
}
```

También te aconsejo que revises la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#introduction) del laravel, hay describe como puedes filtrar y las funciones que puedes realizar para el manejo de modelos,

Comment: si, no me había dado cuenta, gracias por la corrección.

Comment: maravillosa explicación, pero sigo con el mismo problema de la que comenté anteriormente, sigo haciendo varias peticiones separadas en lugar de hacer una sola, sí he visto la documentación de Eloquent  pero nosé inglés, y la traducción es bastante mala... podrías hacerme otro ejemplo similar a este pero que englomere todas las tablas mencionadas en el problema con una única consulta?. No te estoy pidiendo que me hagas el trabajo, simplemente quisiera saber si estoy yendo a buen paso, o estoy realizando una mala práctica, desde ya gracias.

Comment: lo leí como unas 50 veces y pude entenderlo, muchisimas gracias